# Here API offset map center

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using the Here Android SDK API.
I set position indicator via:

```
positionManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);
map.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);
map.getPositionIndicator().setAccuracyIndicatorVisible(true);
```

together with NavigationManager:

```
navMngr.setMapUpdateMode(NavigationManager.MapUpdateMode.ROADVIEW);
```

My map use isometric view:

```
clusterMap.setTilt(60);
```

Thats works, but position indicator apears at the center of the screen. I need to set some offset (or padding) in order to display position indicator way below the center (some offset or padding), so driver could see more of the road ahead. Can't find anything for setting padding for position indicator and binding to view center (only for regular map markers).

Any help would be appreciated<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the transform center of the map at the screen position where you want the user position to be at. That is how we accomplish it.

Comment: Thanks. try this method before, but it was not obvious what coordinates to use - map view relative or screen relative. figured that out. Also want to thank you for all your community efforts here at stack overflow connected to Here Map SDK. It really helpful)

Comment: No problem! I am one of the authors of the HERE Mobile SDK, along with AndrewJC. We hope the SDK works well :)

Answer (score 2):

to achive navigation look and view set transform center to lower than center

```
PointF pc = m_map.getTransformCenter();
PointF pointF = new PointF(pc.x,pc.y* 85/50);
m_map.setTransformCenter(pointF);
```