# How to display my location button on Here Maps for Android

Tags: android, geolocation, here-api

I am using the Here map api to show the here map in android fragment. I am successful in showing the here map in fragment. But i cannot able to show "My Location" button on left corner of here map. (I am using the premium plan)
So, How do I show my location button on a Here Map?

> For google map api, we can add "My current location" button like
>   explained in
>   ([How to display my location on Google Maps for Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142089/how-to-display-my-location-on-google-maps-for-android-api-v2)).
>   I am looking for the same functionality using Here api.

Comment: It looks like they don't have an equivalent to the "My Location" button.  However, they have the [PositionIndicator](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-starter/topics/map-positioning.html) class, take a look here for an example of how to use it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325005/here-api-offset-map-center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in location button UI for the HERE SDK as there is for the Google SDK. You will have to implement the button UI yourself and have it call `Map#setCenter(GeoCoordinate point, Animation animation)` [1] when pressed. You can get the current location to hand to `setCenter` using the `PositioningManager#getPosition()` API [2].

- [1] [Map setCenter API Reference](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-map.html#topic-apiref__setcenter-geocoordinate-map-animation)
- [2] [Positioning User Guide](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics/map-positioning.html) and [PositioningManager API Reference](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-common-positioningmanager.html)

Comment: P.S. You can also have a look at https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples for more examples of using the HERE SDK for Android but I don't believe there is explicitly an example of implementing a "my location" button.